# node-cryptonote-pool v0.99.3.3 Mining into Exchanges

Tags: mining-pools, cryptonote

Hey if anyone can help here .. feel free please . i have noticed a few pools using the software in the header description allowing miners to add there rig worker and payment Id. In order to mine directly into the exchanges.also allowing them to monitor there rigs if they have multiple rigs running.where could i find more info on getting this code to make it work 
Thanks